# How to change title of UILabel when they create themselve in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, initialization

I override draw func in UIButton class and i need to set unique label for this button when he create themselve.

When i use `super.titleLabel?.text = "But Me"` - this is working, but before first click on button. After click, title change to standart "Button". Please help.

P.S.: title label must be set up into UIButton class, not into ViewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set button title as below :

```
button.setTitle("Button Title",for: .normal)
```

Comment: Where i must change in? Into "override func draw ()" ??

Comment: put it into override didLayoutSubviews()

Comment: Thanks! Everybody is all right. Why in don't working as i do it?

Comment: is it subclass of uibutton ?

Comment: Yes. I use it as subclass with special interface and functionality.

Comment: then you need to add this line in awakeFromNib().

Comment: Ok, thank you.
Can you answer: what difference near this two ways (your & my)??

Comment: because titleLabel has a readonly property so you can not set title of label ?